# facebook post to friend's wall

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I used following to post on my own wall.

```
$result = $app->facebook->api('/me/feed/',
                        'post',
                        $attachment);
```

which worked nicely. Now I need to post to my friend's wall. So I used,

```
$result = $app->facebook->api('/'.$rid.'/feed/',
                        'post',
                        $attachment);
```

This, though is not working. Any extra permission or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions), `publish_stream` should be all you need.

(If this does not work, then you ought to provide more information. Can you do some error handling and retrieve an error code of some kind?)