# Facebook application - how to post dynamic content on user's wall post

Tags: java, php, facebook, image, facebook-wall

I have a facebook application that generates a dynamic HTML output based on the user's profile information. Basically it consists of some pics from user's album and some text too like birthday and location. The entire output is in a HTML table. But it is dynamic. Now I want to post this (dynamic) output on the user's wall.

All the posts which I have come across so far, tell how to post a comment on user's wall, either a plain text or a fixed static image. But I want to post my output onto the wall. I have also seen many such applications where the output is posted on the user's wall as well as stored in the user's photo album too!!!

I thought of taking a runtime screenshot of the output, save it, and post it as a static image. But couldn't get much help on this.

I have designed my application in PHP. If required I can migrate it to JAVA (if no other option is there).

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook post to friend's wall.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595158/facebook-post-to-friends-wall)

Comment: a magic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+facebook+wall

Comment: all these links show how to post some text or a static image with a fixed path on the server. Nowhere I find the information to post dynamic HTML content. Mostly, the screenshot option should work. But I am unable to find that too.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think FB lets you post HTML content (manually and through API). Take a look at this [question about how to upload photo using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718610/upload-photo-to-album-with-facebooks-graph-api).